# Create hundreds of uiview and move them from right to left then dealloc them

Tags: ios, drawrect

In view, there will be some title or image.
First, i want to init them and add some lable or imageview,  then use animation to move them. But i think it will not be efficient.
How can i do it efficiently? Thanks all.

Comment: Do they need to be UI views? Could you use something like SpriteKit with its SKSpriteNode and SKLabelNode? This renders the images and labels on the GPU so it would be much faster.

Comment: If you want to do animation, you will use "OpenGLES" framework. Read "https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html" this.

Comment: @Acey Because i want to adapte iOS6, so I can't use SKSpriteNode...Thanks for answer

Comment: @user3833571 I will be learn it at future:). How about use drawRect() in custom view?